# ember cli build slow with babel includePolyfill

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, babeljs

why is babel so slow with `includePolyfill: true`

I have latest version of 
"ember-cli": "2.3.0"
and 
"ember-cli-babel": "^5.1.5"

```
Build successful - 126129ms.

Slowest Trees                                 | Total
----------------------------------------------+---------------------
Babel                                         | 38205ms
JSHint app- QUnit                             | 36606ms
Babel                                         | 29282ms

Slowest Trees (cumulative)                    | Total (avg)
----------------------------------------------+---------------------
Babel (14)                                    | 77556ms (5539 ms)
JSHint app- QUnit (1)                         | 36606ms
```

without polyfill

```
Build successful - 6896ms.

Slowest Trees                                 | Total
----------------------------------------------+---------------------
Babel                                         | 452ms

Slowest Trees (cumulative)                    | Total (avg)
----------------------------------------------+---------------------
Babel (14)                                    | 1797ms (128 ms)
Funnel: Addon JS (9)                          | 555ms (61 ms)
```

Comment: What platform are you building on?

Comment: Was the `includePolyfill` build the first build in the directory? What do the build times look like if you try turning `includePolyfill: flase`, delete the `tmp` and `dist` folders, and then rebuild?

Comment: Are this initial build times or rebuild times?

Comment: initial build with empty tmp and dist folder

Comment: if I use `app.import('vendor/polyfill.min.js');` then everything is ok, if I use `includePolyfill: true` then all is awfully slow and node.js consumes lot of cpu

Comment: have you found any solution? I am having very huge initial build and rebuild times too

Answer (score 1):

Babel is slower with 'includePolyfill' because it has to process the JS more than what it usually does!